# Relation between Critical Path and the Longest Path

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

The Critical Path is the essence of solving the `parallel precedence-constrained scheduling` problem.

The problem: Given a set of jobs of specified duration to be completed, with precedence constraints that specify that certain jobs have to be completed before certain other jobs are begun, how can we schedule the jobs on identical processors (as many as needed) such that they are all completed in the minimum amount of time while still respecting the constraints?

I'm having a tough time understanding the connection between this and the longest path through the graph, which is apparently the solution. I would assume that the answer would be the shortest time because we want the minimum amount of time. Why is this related to the longest path, not the shortest path?

Answer (score 1):

The length of the shortest schedule is related to the longest path because there is nothing you can do, no matter how many processors you have, to get the job done faster than the longest path. No job on the longest path can start before the previous job is finished, so you have to do them one after the other.

If you never run out of processors, you can always start a job as soon as all the jobs it depends on have finished, so each job gets finished as soon as the longest path to its end point finishes, and the whole job finishes when you have completed the longest path.

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest path also work though? As long as it gets through all the vertices and follows the precedence constraints, I don't see why it wouldn't work. "No job on the longest path can start before the previous job has finished", isn't the whole point to have them run concurrently when possible to minimize the amount of time?

Comment: The longest path is the longest path in a very select club of paths - those which are formed by linking tasks with precedence relationships. A path can't join this subset unless each task in it must wait for the one before to end before it can start. A path which has two tasks which could both be done in parallel is excluded. All such paths provide potential minimum times for doing the job, because the job cannot possibly be done quicker than the sum of the task time in the path. The longest is more interesting because at least one hour is a stronger statement than at least five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a vertex representing the end state.
2. Create one vertex for every task.
3. For each task T

   1. For each task T2 that depends on T (and for the end state)

      1. Create a directed edge E from T's vertex to T2's vertex
      2. Set weight of the E to the time required for T.

Then, the critical path is the longest path through the graph. Think about this for a bit, and convince this is true.

*This train of thought helps me:*

The critical path must start with a task with no dependencies and end at the final state. No task can be completed until all of its dependencies are met.

If task A must be done before B, and B must be done before C, then time from task A to task C is at least A->B + B->C.

If C has another dependency B' which has a dependency A, then the time from A to C is at least A->B' + B'->C.

Thus, the *longest* path from A to C is what matters.

The shortest path would solve the problem if *some* dependency of a task had to be met. The longest path solves the problem when *all* dependencies have to be met.